# Do you have to kill timers in mfc?

Tags: c++, mfc

Do you have to make sure to kill all active Timers before closing/destroying an MFC dialog?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A timer is associated with a window. It is destroyed when the windows is destroyed. You don't have to do that explicitly.

However, if you want to do it, then you should kill the timer when the window is destroyed. The best place is do to that when handling the `WM_DESTROY` message.

Comment: Depends on the timer, `CreateTimerQueueTimer` is a diffent beast.